# Tensorflow training with batch size of (1, None, features), but model expects extra dimension

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I've made an autoencoder like below, to accept variable-length inputs. It works for a single sample if I do `model.fit(np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)` but this won't work when passing in an entire dataset. What's the simplest approach in this case?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Lambda
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model


def repeat(x):
    step_matrix = K.ones_like(x[0][:, :, :1])
    latent_matrix = K.expand_dims(x[1], axis = 1)
    return K.batch_dot(step_matrix, latent_matrix)

timesteps = None
features = 2
latent_dim = 10

inputs = Input(shape = (timesteps, features))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim, name = "encoded")(inputs)
decoded = Lambda(repeat)([inputs, encoded])
outputs = LSTM(features, return_sequences = True)(decoded)
autoenc = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs)
autoenc.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "mse")
encoder = Model(
    inputs = autoenc.input, outputs = autoenc.get_layer("encoded").output
)

x1 = np.ones((20, 2))
x2 = np.ones((30, 2))
x3 = np.ones((40, 2))
X_train = np.array((x1, x2, x3))

autoenc.fit(x = X_train, y = X_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 1)
```

Comment: What is the dimension of X_train? Have you checked it?

Comment: The problem is, for example, that the first sample is shape (20, 2), but the model expects it to be (1, 20, 2). This only happens with batch size 1.

Comment: What you asked is rather expected. Reducing batch_size does not change the input shape even if you have 1 as batch size you still require 3 dimensions. This is for easier paralelization.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem with a generator, which expands the dimensions for each single batch to return shape `(1, None, 2)`.

```
class SingleBatchGenerator:
    def __init__(self, X):
        self.X = X

    def __call__(self):
        for i in range(len(self.X)):
            xi = np.expand_dims(self.X[i], axis=0)
            yield xi, xi

X = [np.ones((np.random.randint(1, 100), 2)) for _ in range(100)]
gen = SingleBatchGenerator(X)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator = gen,
    output_types=(tf.float64, tf.float64),
    output_shapes=((1, None, 2), (1, None, 2)),
)

autoenc.fit(ds.repeat(), steps_per_epoch=len(X), epochs=500)
```